# Unknown validator: 'BeforeValidator' when validating date in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, devise

I'm adding a validator inside the User.rb model to validate the birthdate given is over 18 years old before create the devise user.

This is the validation I have.

```
# user.rb
validates :birthdate, :before => lambda { 18.years.ago }, :before_message => "must be at least 18 years old"
```

Inside the User schema

```
# User schema
t.date     "birthdate"
```

Problem is that I'm getting the following error when trying to save the object.

```
ArgumentError in Devise::RegistrationsController#create

Unknown validator: 'BeforeValidator'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Unknown validator: 'BeforeValidator'` means you've overestimated the magic :)

Try this:

```
validate do |user|
  if user.birthdate > 18.years.ago
    errors.add(:birthdate, "must be at least 18 years old")
  end
end
```

Comment: You don't have to define a custom validator :) see `validates` documentation or [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10306906/186424)

Comment: @Andión, no, I don't. And I didn't :) Custom validators are objects with `validate_each` method. So you were distracted during reading docs. And your code is completely WRONG. You're trying to compare Date and Fixnum (18).

Comment: OOOps, yes it is totally wrong, thanks for pointing it out. When I was saying a custom validation (meaning your answer) I missused the name the same silly way I confused birthdate with age :( I was trying to express my dislike of people doing lambda validations when you don't have to. But in this case yoy are totally right :)

Comment: So, as you see: there is no silver bullet. You must use at least lambdas because otherwise `18.years.ago` will be saved once it calculated and will remain the same all the time. Glad that you've solved your misunderstandings!

Answer (score 0):

You can also try:

```
before_validation :validade_birth_date

private

def validade_birth_date
    if (birthdate != nil)
      errors.add(:birthdate, "must be at least 18 years old") unless (birthdate < DateTime.now)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

`:before` is not an actual default [validator](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#validation-helpers) of ActiveRecord. When validates finds any validator name it doesn't know, it searches one custom validator with its name (in this case BeforeValidation)

All validations are made before the actual object is stored by nature, and you don't have to make your own validator as pointed out. ActiveRecord already provides one: [`:numericality`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#numericality)

```
validates :birthdate, :numericality => { :greater_than => 18 , :message => "must be at least %{count} years old" }
```